# Reason for higher content of Iodine and Copper than Iron in Seawater?

Tags: ocean, geochemistry, water, salinity

Does mineral weight contribute to the [prevalence of minerals](https://web.stanford.edu/group/Urchin/mineral.html) in seawater?

Why is there five times more copper in seawater than Iron?
Why is there 4000 times more strontium in seawather than Iron, when strontium is 30% heavier?

Comment: short answer, solubility. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility

Comment: living things need iron,a part of the answer is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_fertilization

Comment: I figure that's why crabs have blue blood that uses copper. copper is Cu++ and iron is Fe++.